# Substr based on bytes rather than character count

Tags: javascript, byte

I'm creating an input system where a fields maximum value can only be 200 bytes. I am counting the remaining number of bytes by using the following (this method might but up for debate, too!):

```
var totalBytes = 200;
var $newVal = $(this).val();
var m = encodeURIComponent($newVal).match(/%[89ABab]/g);
var bytesLeft = totalBytes - ($newVal.length + (m ? m.length : 0));
```

This appears to work well, however if someone were to paste in a large chunk of data, I want to be able to slice the input and only show 200 bytes of it. I guess in psuedo-code that would look something like :

```
$newText = substrBytes($string, 0, 200);
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

**Edit** : Everything going on here is UTF-8 btw :)

**Edit 2** : I'm aware that I can loop every character and evaluate, I think I was hoping there might be something a little more graceful to take care of this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason to treat your input as bytes and not text ? see the string methods at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: I may be wrong but I have the impression that this will require some sort of iconv-like conversion between character encodings. Doesn't sound easy.

Comment: The system this is plugging into requires text payload size to be no larger than 200 bytes.

Comment: I actually had the same problem a while ago: in Oracle, you can define a column as `VARCHAR(4000 CHAR)` but it cannot hold more than 4000 bytes, no matter the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google search yielded [a blog article](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/javascript-validating-utf-8-string.html), complete with a try-it-yourself input box. I'm copying the code here because SO likes definitive answers rather than links, but credit goes to [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell).

```
/**
 * codePoint - an integer containing a Unicode code point
 * return - the number of bytes required to store the code point in UTF-8
 */
function utf8Len(codePoint) {
  if(codePoint >= 0xD800 && codePoint <= 0xDFFF)
    throw new Error("Illegal argument: "+codePoint);
  if(codePoint < 0) throw new Error("Illegal argument: "+codePoint);
  if(codePoint <= 0x7F) return 1;
  if(codePoint <= 0x7FF) return 2;
  if(codePoint <= 0xFFFF) return 3;
  if(codePoint <= 0x1FFFFF) return 4;
  if(codePoint <= 0x3FFFFFF) return 5;
  if(codePoint <= 0x7FFFFFFF) return 6;
  throw new Error("Illegal argument: "+codePoint);
}

function isHighSurrogate(codeUnit) {
  return codeUnit >= 0xD800 && codeUnit <= 0xDBFF;
}

function isLowSurrogate(codeUnit) {
  return codeUnit >= 0xDC00 && codeUnit <= 0xDFFF;
}

/**
 * Transforms UTF-16 surrogate pairs to a code point.
 * See RFC2781
 */
function toCodepoint(highCodeUnit, lowCodeUnit) {
  if(!isHighSurrogate(highCodeUnit)) throw new Error("Illegal argument: "+highCodeUnit);
  if(!isLowSurrogate(lowCodeUnit)) throw new Error("Illegal argument: "+lowCodeUnit);
  highCodeUnit = (0x3FF & highCodeUnit) << 10;
  var u = highCodeUnit | (0x3FF & lowCodeUnit);
  return u + 0x10000;
}

/**
 * Counts the length in bytes of a string when encoded as UTF-8.
 * str - a string
 * return - the length as an integer
 */
function utf8ByteCount(str) {
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if(isHighSurrogate(ch)) {
      var high = ch;
      var low = str.charCodeAt(++i);
      count += utf8Len(toCodepoint(high, low));
    } else {
      count += utf8Len(ch);
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: This snippet is very interesting but results seem to change depending on the encoding of the file that holds the source code. But it's probably great for forms.

Comment: Although this code snippet doesn't actualy have the slice function that I was looking for, it handles the byte counting perfectly. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JavaScript are represented in UTF-16 internally, so every character take actually two bytes. So your question is more like "Get bytes length of str in UTF-8".

Hardly you need half of a symbol, so it may cut 198 or 199 bytes.

Here're 2 different solutions:

```
// direct byte size counting
function cutInUTF8(str, n) {
    var len = Math.min(n, str.length);
    var i, cs, c = 0, bytes = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = str.charCodeAt(i);
        cs = 1;
        if (c >= 128) cs++;
        if (c >= 2048) cs++;
        if (c >= 0xD800 && c < 0xDC00) {
            c = str.charCodeAt(++i);
            if (c >= 0xDC00 && c < 0xE000) {
                cs++;
            } else {
                // you might actually want to throw an error
                i--;
            }
        }
        if (n < (bytes += cs)) break;
    }
    return str.substr(0, i);
}

// using internal functions, but is not very fast due to try/catch
function cutInUTF8(str, n) {
    var encoded = unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)).substr(0, n);
    while (true) {
        try {
            str = decodeURIComponent(escape(encoded));
            return str;
        } catch(e) {
            encoded = encoded.substr(0, encoded.length-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First function triggers `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` in the `if (n < bytes += cs) break;` line. Second function apparently returns the complete string no matter the argument.

Comment: This is a great answer, just not quite as in depth as the above answer. If I could mark them both as correct, I would! Thanks!

Comment: Note that the direct byte size counting answer will not work for characters that cannot be represented with a single UTF-16 character.

For example, the following string "" is 4 `utf-8` bytes, but the byte counting logic says it's 6. Alternatively, you can use [Buffer. byteLength](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding). If you're on a browser, you can use [webpack for a polyfill](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/#node-buffer).

Comment: @Marco I have fixed it. There's second function, which works OK. For modern browsers I can also recommend [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder)